# How to create content drop down menu bars?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create content drop down bars as shown in images. When someone clicks on that bar then content show and if he clicks again drop down should hide. I searched for this but not got any good solution. So please help me with this, refer image for understanding my query.

Image:

[image]

Comment: Had you tried anything to achieve above ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add up/down arrows to Bootstrap Accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777704/add-up-down-arrows-to-bootstrap-accordion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I would achieve this by a tiny customization with JQueryUI Accordion. Please refer this example:

https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use bootstrap which have some more functionalities.

See example below. 
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible_accordion&stacked=h

By the way Bootstrap 4 is released but I am linking Bootstrap 3.